# position:absolute with display:flex squishes elements together?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

In my nav bar i have 4 `<li>` items  which on `:hover` i would like a drop-down menu to appear under the `<li>` element which has 3 different links.

The problem is when `:hover` is active the drop-down displays but then the 3 other `<li>` elements move underneath the nav bar when they should not move at all.

I have tried using `position:absolute` on  `nav ul li` elements but that just squishes them all on top of each other.

**nav bar**

[image]

**nav ul li:hover**

[image]

**`nav ul li` {position:absolute;}**

[image]

*html*

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <button>Home</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link A</a>
                <a href="#">Link B</a>
                <a href="#">Link C</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button>Profile</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link A</a>
                <a href="#">Link B</a>
                <a href="#">Link C</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        ...
        ..
        .
    </ul>
</nav>
```

*css*

```
nav {
    border-bottom: 0.1rem rgb(228, 220, 220) solid;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    height: 3rem;
    background-color: white;
    top:0;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    position: absolute;
}

nav ul li {
    /* position:absolute; */
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

nav ul li button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: medium;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0.1rem rgb(228, 220, 220) solid;
    border-top: none;
    margin-top: 0.8rem;
    width: 5rem;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0.4rem 0 0.4rem;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

nav ul li:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute position should be added to the `dropdown-content` div. You can find an example below :

```css
nav {
    border-bottom: 0.1rem rgb(228, 220, 220) solid;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    height: 3rem;
    background-color: white;
    top:0;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: medium;
    height: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0.1rem rgb(228, 220, 220) solid;
    border-top: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 5rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% - 1px);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0.4rem 0 0.4rem;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

nav ul li:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <button>Home</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link A</a>
                <a href="#">Link B</a>
                <a href="#">Link C</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button>Profile</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link A</a>
                <a href="#">Link B</a>
                <a href="#">Link C</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This solves problem of the other `li` elements moving out of the nav. But now the dropdown-content and li elements are not aligned in the center (vertically).

Comment: You can add a `left: -10px;` on the `dropdown-content` class if you want